# ssrs:I have 2 piecharts in design,but only 1 is showing up in preview.can som1 pls help me solve it

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 pie charts in design , but only 1 is showing up in preview. can someone please help me solve it? I'm very new to ssrs and I don't know what to try

Comment: Are both charts bound to the same data source?

Comment: @mindparse Yes,they are

Comment: when I change the chart type to line or bar,It shows up in preview but when I change back to piechart,It doesn't show

Comment: Hmm that is odd, must be a config issue on the pie chart, I'm guessing you have compared the properties, series sources, etc with the chart that does show? I guess you are using different values for the second chart?

Comment: @user4530629 Add rectangle on page and put both chart on it..i think i will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

@mindparse @manoj I had changed a column name in my table and forgot to update it in ssrs.. So that was causing the issue. Thanx guys for your help